# Bachelors degree (+- 16 years)

Tags: job-search, applications, job-description

I saw this on an online application for a job:

```
Education level:
Bachelor's Degree (±16 years)
```

I have not seen this on any other applications of the sort. What does the ±16 years mean?

Comment: I'd guess it's a typo and should just be (+16 years).  If alternate educational levels with different numbers of years (eg associates and 18 years or masters and 14) that would reinforce my assumption.

Comment: Some countries have 14 years of education for Bachelor degree, Probably the ad was asking for more of a *regular* bachelor degree.

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: this is the united states. I doubt it is a typo, because it showed up multiple times for multiple levels of education. Eg, `High School or GED (±11 years)`

Comment: As @ChrisLively says, the ± is used in some countries to mean approximately.  The Netherlands is one such country.  Likely the resume is or job posting is from someone who comes from a country where ± is used like that.

Comment: so, is this probably because the company is international? They have their headquarters in Japan and hiring around the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

± is going to mean "about" or "approximately" or even "give or take a bit".

Essentially it's saying that the person spent about 16 years of their life in school.

Answer (score 3):

I'd second Dan's comment that this is the number of years of formal education. In Canada there are 12 grades of elementary and secondary school, which isn't counting pre-school and Kindergarten, then adding 4 years for a Bachelor's degree would give a total of 16 years of education. I'd suspect in the US there could be similar totals giving that number of years of total schooling.

Comment: so counting your primary reception class seems a little strange what value does it have?

Comment: That's rather different than my guess, which was that they were co-mingling degree level and professional experience and wanted someone with a BS/BA degree and 16 years of work experience, but yours seems reasonable as well.

Comment: Going along the same lines, a 3 Year Degree in Australia counts as a 4 Year degree in the US as we have a extra year of Secondary Education. The final year of high school counts as a year of college.